# Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys/auto/XML/LibXML/Common/Common.dll' for module XML::LibXML::Common: dlopen: Win32 error 126

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, perl-module

I'm stuck with this error:

```
Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys/auto/XML/LibXML/Common/Common.dll' for module XML::LibXML::Common: dlopen: Win32 error 126 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8
/msys/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys/XML/LibXML.pm line 12
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys/XML/LibXML.pm line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys/XML/LibXML.pm line 12.

Compilation failed in require at script.pl line 5.    
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script.pl line 5.
```

while loading a perl script which uses `XML::Libxml`.

It worked perfectly last week, so I'm sure I don't have any syntax error or path error.

I can't read the error nor understand it....

Here is my script, very simple :

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use utf8; 
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use XML::LibXML;
    require "D:/Projets/Maroc Scada/Rabat 41 - Images T200i-DRR-F200C/script_PI/addresses.pl";

    my $Filepath = "D:/Projets/Maroc Scada/Rabat 41 - Images T200i-DRR-F200C/script_PI/RTUS_originaux";     # Must contain a "treated" subdirectory to store results
    my $parser;         # LibXML object used to read the text file .xml
    my $xmldoc;         # XML document parsed, ready to use with libxml API
    my $i = 0;          # treated elements per file
    my $j = 0;          # treated files
    my $RTUName;        # Name of the current RTU
    my $RTUType;        # Type of the RTU. matching the key in %address hash table in addresses.pl
    my $MeasureName;    # Current Measure Name (for printing in console)
    my $Parameters;     # parameters to apply to on the node. Typically a hash containing key->values of the parameters to be updated as { "MonitorTcAddress" => "11", ... }
    my $v = 0;          # 1 for more debug information. If 0, only errors and message "end of program"

    # Get the files in the given directory and loop on all xml files exported from PowerCC
    print "Beginning of program...\n";
    opendir(DIR, $Filepath);
    my @FILES= readdir(DIR); 
    foreach my $File (@FILES) {

        if ($File =~ m/.xml/) {   #  m/.xml$/
            print "Opening ".$File."\n" if $v;
            $j++;
            $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
            $xmldoc = $parser->parse_file($Filepath."/".$File);


            #  Loop on all nodes in xml file to place the default addresses (IOA) 
            #  and the types of the measurements in the RTYType defined in 
            #  the hash in address.pl

            # Loop on all RTUs
            for my $rtu ($xmldoc->findnodes('/XDF/Instances/Parent/CfeSubRemoteTerminalUnit')) {
                $RTUName = $rtu->getAttribute("Name");
                $RTUType = $rtu->getAttribute("Description");
                if (length($RTUType) < 2) { print "[ERROR 002] : Type of RTU is not defined for RTU=".$RTUName."   Type=".$RTUType."\n"; }
                print "RTUName=".$RTUName . ", Type=". $RTUType. "\n"  if $v;

                # Chosing IEC 101 and address structure 24 bits
                $rtu->setAttribute("TeleControlProtocolType", "1");
                $rtu->setAttribute("DataPointAddressStructure", "4");


                # Looking for all Analog measurements
                for my $Measure ($rtu->findnodes('CfeTelemeteredAnalog')) { 
                    $MeasureName = $Measure->getAttribute("Name");
                    $Parameters = getAddress($MeasureName, $RTUType);

                    if ($$Parameters{"RemoveFromPI"}) {             # Special. Point is in PI but doesn't exist in reality -> removing from XML.
                        print "[SPECIAL 005] : Removing node ".$MeasureName." from XML file.\n" if $v;
                        $Measure->unbindNode();
                    }
                    else {
                        # Overwrite all parameters in the Hash $adresses on the attributes of the current node.
                        foreach my $Param (keys %$Parameters)  {
                            $Measure->setAttribute( $Param, $$Parameters{$Param} );
                            print " ".$MeasureName." :      ".$Param." =>   ".$$Parameters{$Param}."\n" if $v;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                } # Analog Iteration


                # Looking for all Digital Status. Same structure. Duplicated code iterating on digital nodes
                for my $Measure ($rtu->findnodes('CfeTelemeteredDigital')) { 
                    $MeasureName = $Measure->getAttribute("Name");
                    $Parameters = getAddress($MeasureName, $RTUType);

                    if ($$Parameters{"RemoveFromPI"}) {             # Special. Point is in PI but doesn't exist in reality -> removing from XML.
                        print "[SPECIAL 006] : Removing node ".$MeasureName." from XML file.\n" if $v;
                        $Measure->unbindNode();
                    }
                    else {
                        # Overwrite all parameters in the Hash $adresses on the attributes of the current node.
                        foreach my $Param (keys %$Parameters)  {
                            $Measure->setAttribute( $Param, $$Parameters{$Param} );
                            print " ".$MeasureName." :      ".$Param." =>   ".$$Parameters{$Param}."\n"   if $v;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                } # Digital iteration


            } # RTU iteration



            # write the xml tree to a text file
            open (MYFILE, '>'.$Filepath.'/treated/'.$File);
            print MYFILE $xmldoc->toString(1);
            close (MYFILE); 
            print "Closing ".$File.". Treated elements = ".$i."\n"  if $v;
        } # if . or ..
    } # loop on files in directory

    print "End of Program. ".$j." XML files treated, ".$i." elements.\n";
```

Comment: It porduces the same error with only the first lines until use XML::LibXML;  so I presume it is the loading of the module that does'nt work anymore....

Comment: Win32 error 126 seems to be "The specified module could not be found". Perhaps your module has been moved. And also, it seems you are using unix paths in windows? Is this script ported from another OS?

Comment: In the line `require "D:/Projets/` there's `c` missing.

Comment: @simbabque: erm, I think this is a French installation. Projet is French for project :)

Comment: @Borodin you're right. I thought one of the two paths he has was written with a 'c' and the other wasn't. My bad.

Comment: @TLP Yes, Unix paths in windows seems strange. But it comes from ActivePerl. I didnt change anything in the ActivePerl configuration so I don't know where these Unix paths come from. Before, it just worked.

Comment: I don't know what, specifically is causing your problem, but I would consider moving to strawberry Perl (http://strawberryperl.com/).  It has a compiler environment that allows you to use the standard CPAN modules.  In my experience, that makes life much easier.

Comment: @dan1111 Thx you for info. I'll try. It is written Perl 5.8 but I install today ActivePerl 5.16, which is the latest I found. COuld it be a problem of calling a incorrect version of Perl on my system ? Can I have 2 Perl runtime environnement at the same time ? I defintely want to use the latest version, of course.

Comment: @dan1111 I tried to force Perl5.16 a got this :  perl5.16.1 script.pl
Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @ INC (@ INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at script.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script.pl line 5.      --> But in ppm, I see the module installed ... --> ?

Comment: @StéphaneV, it sounds like you have multiple installations of Perl, possibly messing up the configuration.  Perhaps you should remove all of them and start fresh with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your Perl library has been corrupted, and you should report this to whoever is responsible for maintaining it. If you can do this yourself then simply reinstall `XML::LibXML`

Comment: I reinstall the module XML::libXML but nothing changed. I will try to reinstall ActivePerl. It seems there is a problem down there...