# Perl XML::libXML does'nt work anymore : Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys/auto/XML/LibXML/Common/Common.dll

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys/auto/XML/LibXML/Common/Common.dll' for module XML::LibXML::Common: dlopen: Win32 error 126](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779400/cant-load-usr-lib-perl5-vendor-perl-5-8-msys-auto-xml-libxml-common-common-dl)

I have this dummy script who worked previously :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8; 
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();

print "test ok\n";
```

But today, it trows an error :

```
Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys/auto/XML/LibXML/Common/Common.dll' for module XML::LibXML::Common: dlopen: Win32 error 126 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/msys/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys/XML/LibXML.pm line 12
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys/XML/LibXML.pm line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys/XML/LibXML.pm line 12.
Compilation failed in require at D:\Projets\Maroc Scada\Rabat 41 - Images T200i-DRR-F200C\script_PI\test.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at D:\Projets\Maroc Scada\Rabat 41 - Images T200i-DRR-F200C\script_PI\test.pl line 5.
```

I reinstall Perl completely and reinstall the module libxml-perl 0.08 today but this didn't help.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: How do you install the module? What OS do you have? Which Perl?

Comment: The obvious question here is: what changed on your system around the time that the dummy script stopped working?  (Also, it is worth pointing out that your Perl is very old.  If you don't have a reason to stick with that version, upgrading would be a good idea).

Comment: You should not ask a duplicate of the same question.  If you have additional information, edit your original question to reflect that.  I have flagged this question for deletion.

Comment: @ Dan OK. @Choroba : I used the graphical Perl package manager. @ Dan : Perl very old ? I downloaded today ! How can I uprage to a higher version ?